# POJO stay in memory after use in jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc, profiling, profiler

I have tomcat based servlet. Servlet have mvc based on annotation class, look like (pseudo code)

```
@RequestMapping("/myAction")
public String getAction(Model m) {
     DBConnection conn = new DBConnection();//connect to DB
     Result r = conn.getDataOfAction();//run some sql query and return result
     ArrayList<POJO> list = r.getResult();//24 instances of class, for example
     m.put("list",list); //It's for resolving pojo into JSP page
     String result = CustomViewResolver.getString(viewName, list);//i just point to ViewName and get parsed jsp page
     //list.clear();
     return result;
}
```

When i start profiling with comment `//list.clear()` as is. I have situation when all `POJO` stay in memory even after page already rendered on client side. When i uncomment `//list.clear()` when all `POJO` garbage collected except one which point to forEach `jstl` tag.

[image]

I flushed and closed all `Stream's` and `Writer's` but seems no matter. It is normal way clear list, or i do something wrong? Thanks.

UPD: I try other situation, when i use `jstl`

```
    <c:forEach items=${POJOLIST} var="pojo"></c:forEach>
```

all `pojo's` stay in memory. But if i print `${POJOLIST}` in `jsp` without use of `jstl`, when all pojo garbage collected how i want. `jstl`'s `var` recreate object and keep it in memory?

Comment: Any luck with this issue? We are experiencing it too.

Answer (score 0):

if you use @SessionAttribute or manage the session manually, the "Object Command" stays in session. Therefore, once you're done with the controller, you need to tell the controller your actions are complete and the Sessions variables are not useful anymore and are ready to be cleaned:

```
@RequestMapping("/myAction")
public String getAction(Model m, SessionStatus status) {
     ....
     m.put("list",list); 
     status.setComplete(); //tells the controller you're done with your actions and will clean all sessions variables
     return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I experienced while profiling my application. Turns out because  `enablePooling` is turned on in web.xml jsp servlet by default, objects will not be released as you would expect. Only solution is to turn off enablePooling. Have a look at these two bugs that were raised

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25623

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16001

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same problem lately.
I've done googling to solve the problem for a long time..
Finally I solved it by setting `enablePooling` to `false` in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml`.
(default value of the parameter is true.)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>enablePooling</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```